# Is there an addon to enable export of Blender object to an Objective-C header?

Tags: export, add-on, file-format

I have used a third party addon script to do this, but it is throwing an error:

> AttributeError: Mesh object does not contain faces attribute.

It complains about the line `for face in object.data.faces:`

It was originally written for Blender 2.57 and apparently no longer works.
Is there some other addon for 2.70?

Comment: IIRC `faces` was replaced with [`polygons`](http://www.blender.org/documentation/blender_python_api_2_70_release/bpy.types.Mesh.html#bpy.types.Mesh.polygons). You could try and correct the offending lines, idk if that's feasible.

Comment: Thanks Gandalf, I replaced faces with polygons and same error.  I replaced "for face in object.data.faces" with "for face in object.data.polygons".

Comment: For info, the script can be viewed at GITHub and is called io_export_objective_c_header.py written for 2.57 by a Jeff LaMarche. 

Comment: With 2.63's introduction of BMesh intregration, plugins which operate on mesh data need to be reworked to use the newer API for using loops. Renaming the accessor is not enough.

Comment: I can fix it, but I need to know how to handle Quads and NGons. Shoud everything be auto-triangulated? Which method? (fixed, fixed alternate, beauty, shortest diagonal). Shall it use vertex normals, or split vertex normals (per loop, to support mixed - smooth and sharp - edges).

Comment: Did you try the latest version? [objc_blend_2.62](https://github.com/jlamarche/iOS-OpenGLES-Stuff/tree/master/Blender%20Export/objc_blend_2.62) does not contain `.faces` anywhere - so seems to be compatible with 2.63+

Comment: CoDEmanX your a genius and saved me much agro, if you weren't virtual I'd give you a big man hug.  Your link there works a treat, I must have had an old link and didn't realise you could get an updated version.

Comment: How do I mark this as answered?

Comment: Anyone who's interested this add on that CoDEmanX has found the latest version of, now allows a header file to be created with all the vertices, normal and uv coordinates for displaying objects in OpenGL in IOS apps.

Answer (score 1):

Did you try the latest version? There's one called `objc_blend_2.62`, which does not contain `.faces` anywhere in the code - so seems to be compatible with 2.63+ (and funnily not with 2.62!)

Link: [objc_blend_2.62 @ Github](https://github.com/jlamarche/iOS-OpenGLES-Stuff/tree/master/Blender%20Export/objc_blend_2.62)